# Link EKPO-EBELP and G/L accounts

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, sap-erp

I want to know which order position (EBELP from EKPO in SAP MM) appear in which G/L account (HKONT in BSEG in SAP FI with koart = 'S').

I'm working with SQL queries on a redshift database which has the tables copied from SAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found an answer after a couple of days looking through forums and SAP tables column by column... since I am mainly interested in connecting order positions to G/L accounts, I was able to find them in EKKN which is directly linkable to EKPO. For some ebelp there are multiple sakto which is why we need "vproz" to be able to divide the EKPO-NETWR into the different sakto.

Going through all of it also made me shift my question from linking EKPO and BSEG to linking EKPO-EBELP and the G/L accounts. The BSEG-HKONT (with filter to BSEG-KOART = 'S') are also in EKKN-SAKTO.

```
SELECT ebeln, ebelp, netwr, sakto, vproz, vproz * netwr / 100 AS sakto_netwr
FROM ekpo
LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT
          mandt
          ,ebeln
          ,ebelp
          ,sakto
          ,SUM(vproz) as vproz
          FROM ekkn
          GROUP BY mandt, ebeln, ebelp, sakto
          )
          ekkn ON ekkn.mandt = ekpo.mandt AND ekkn.ebeln = ekpo.ebeln AND ekkn.ebelp = ekpo.ebelp
```

Comment: To improve the performance (and make your query fully valid), you should add the `MANDT` column for all tables: it's the first column of their primary keys!

Answer (score 1):

> which has the tables copied from SAP.

If you copied **ALL** the tables you can improve your query in a following manner.

There is a wonderful table `EKBE` which is order document history and resembles all order data from `EKPO`. It contains both order numbers and corresponding material document numbers

```
EKBE:          MSEG:

BELNR   ->     MBLNR

GJAHR   ->     MJAHR

BUZEI   ->     ZEILE
```

This totally eliminates the need of `MSEG`/`MKPF` in your horrendous query. Probable SELECT can be following:

```
SELECT ekbe.ebeln, ekbe.ebelp, bseg.hkont
  FROM ekbe
  LEFT JOIN bkpf ON bkpf.mandt = ekbe.mandt AND left(bkpf.awkey,10) = ekbe.belnr AND right(left(bkpf.awkey,14),4) = ekbe.gjahr AND bkpf.awtyp = 'RMRP'
  LEFT JOIN bseg ON bseg.mandt = bkpf.mandt AND bseg.bukrs = bkpf.bukrs AND bseg.gjahr = bkpf.gjahr AND bseg.belnr = bkpf.belnr
```

Note that field `AWTYP` should also be specified in `JOIN`, because any accounting doc can have many materials of different types in the year (`AWKEY` = `<object number>` + `<year>`).

Also, I do not appreciate the order you join the tables in your original SELECT. Usually source data table (`EKPO` in our case as we are searching account for each purchase order) is putted first and all others are joined to her. 
But it is a matter of taste and also a matter of Redshift syntax which you knows better.

Comment: cluster table like BSEG cannot be joined directly.

Comment: he copied all tables to Amazon Redshift, in Redshift backend clusterness has no sense anymore

Comment: i just ran your code and I got multiple hkonts for one ebelp, as well as multiple material numbers from BSEG for one of EKPO (joined to EKBE). It seems the query joins all order positions in BSEG to the one position in EKBE. 

Is there a way of knowing which line in BSEG is which position of an order in EKBE (basically ebelp)?

Comment: I'd rather not add join parameters on material in case there happen to be two order positions of the same material in one order by any chance.

Comment: `i just ran your code and I got multiple hkonts for one ebelp, as well as multiple material numbers from BSEG for one of EKPO (joined to EKBE)` it's normal situation and absolutely conforms ERP data model. Exemplified [on my sample dataset](https://i.imgur.com/uuZ2lf1.png): one order (EBELN) can have many positions (EBELP), one order position can have many corresponding material docs (BELNR) which can have many materials and vice versa, each material (MATNR) can have many different mat.docs.[->>](https://i.imgur.com/fFckA0z.png).

Comment: Making things more complicated, each material document from MSEG can have many-to-many relation with BSEG and [there is no way to coincide](http://www.sapfans.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=44218) BSEG position (BUZEI) with MSEG position (ZEILE)

Comment: And also forgot to add `mandt` condition to JOIN as absolutely fairly noted by Sandra. Otherwise your SELECT will not be valid, if you copied all clients data from SAP. Corrected my asnwer.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear - in your query one EBELP from EKPO -> EKBE -> BKPF -> BSEG returns all hkonts of all other EBELPs of the same EBELN and not just the one fitting to the position itself. Further example: If I add BSEG-matnr to the select I also see all other materials from different ebelps of the same ebeln. I just want the hkont of the one ebelp from EKPO, not all hkonts of the ebeln from EKPO.

Comment: also, can you exaplain bkpf.awtyp = 'RMRP' in your solution?

Comment: `in your query one EBELP returns all hkonts of all other EBELPs of the same EBELN` how did you found out that? Are you sure that the same BELNR is not contained in different EBELPs [like in my dataset](https://i.imgur.com/fFckA0z.png)? HKONT lays in bseg table which has primary key by position (BUZEI). As I already noted it is impossible to unambiguously associate bseg position (HKONT) with mseg position and thus with EBELP too.Anyway this conversation has no sense w/o your real data. Post the samples of ekbe/ekpo/bseg/mseg tables and we will see

Comment: `also, can you exaplain bkpf.awtyp = 'RMRP' in your solution?` it's just a sample, you should replace it with your type depending of what kind of acc doc you are searching (RMRP for invoice, PORD for order etc.)